# How do you pass a variable into a subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with 5 datetimes that are a text datatype. The values are `4/15/12 1:47` (type FT), `9/8/12 20:02` (type FT), `5/10/13 22:21` (type FT), `3/3/13 4:46` (type FT), and `2/9/12 4:19` (type NL). I want to count the number of events that occur in each hour then divide it by the total events.

Since the column is in a text datatype, I select the hour with the following code: `hour(str_to_Date(order_placer_placed_time,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%i')`.

The code I have tried is

```
select (
(select count(*) from col where type = 'ft' and hour(str_to_Date(time,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%i')) = 4
group by type)
/count(*)) as 'FT %', 
hour(str_to_Date(time,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%i')) as hour
from col
group by hour
order by hour;
```

I need to change the `4` in my subquery to all the hour segments in each day so I can return a result that shows me the % of 'ft' individuals divided by the total individuals.

I am not sure how to make the `4` in my subquery dynamic to return the results I am looking for.

The final output should look like:

```
1 100%
4 50%
20 100%
22 100%
```

Comment: I am not clear what you are asking for.. What does 'I want to count the number of events that occur in each hour then divide it by the total events' - what is total events  is that over the entire dataset , over a day or within an hour (and if so how is this different from count number of events). AND you cannnot pass a variable to a sub query AND what if no events occur in an hour slot?.

Comment: @P.Salmon So in my column I have 5 datetimes that are one of two categories (ft or nl). For each hour in the database, I want to find the percentage of values that are ft

Comment: Still not clear when you say 5 datetimes do you mean there are 5 datetime columns or 1 column which contains 5 datetimes. sample data(as text) would help togerther with table definition.

Comment: `select 
       100/count(*) as 'FT %',
       hour(str_to_Date(time, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i')) as hour
  from col c
 group by hour` already gives what you want ???

Comment: It’s one column with 5 date times. There is another column called type that has 2 values (ft or nl). Let me know if I can explain this further.

Comment: @barbaros to find the ft% I need to find the count of ft divided by count of *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you just want something like this

```
drop table if exists col;

create table col
(type varchar(3),ts varchar(20));

insert into col values
('ft','1/2/2019 1:47'),('ft','1/2/2019 20:02'),('ft','1/2/2019 22:21'),('ft','1/2/2019 1:47'),('ft','1/2/2019 4:19'),
('ft','1/3/2019 1:47'),('nl','1/3/2019 4:19');

select hour(str_to_Date(ts,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%i')) as hour,
        sum(case when type = 'ft' then 1 else 0 end) obsft,
        count(*) obsall,

        sum(case when type = 'ft' then 1 else 0 end) /
        count(*) * 100 as perft
from col
group by hour(str_to_Date(ts,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%i')) 

union
select 25,
        sum(case when type = 'ft' then 1 else 0 end) obsft,
        count(*) obsall,

        sum(case when type = 'ft' then 1 else 0 end) /
        count(*) * 100 as perft

from col;

+------+-------+--------+----------+
| hour | obsft | obsall | perft    |
+------+-------+--------+----------+
|    1 |     3 |      3 | 100.0000 |
|    4 |     1 |      2 |  50.0000 |
|   20 |     1 |      1 | 100.0000 |
|   22 |     1 |      1 | 100.0000 |
|   25 |     6 |      7 |  85.7143 |
+------+-------+--------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```